# Deprecated Functionality: when running compile

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have two Magento sites both v2.3.3
I have noticed today that I cannot run the compile function:
php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile
I'm getting the following error:

```
Application code generator... 3/7 [=====>-------]  42% 18 secs 254.0 MiB
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:Deprecated Functionality: Array and string offset access syntax with curlybraces is deprecated in /home/customer/www/mystagingsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/GraphQl/Config/Element/FieldFactory.php on line 49
```

I have no idea why or what has caused this.
Has anyone else experienced the same and what is the issue/solution please?
PS. I changed the curly brackets in the file from { } to [ ] on line 49 of the mentioned file but then got the following error:

```
Application code generator... 3/7 [=====>-------]  42% 20 secs 272.0 MiB
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:
Deprecated Functionality: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ?: d` is deprecated. 
Use either `(a ? b : c) ?: d` or `a ? b : (c ?: d)` in /home/customer/www/mystagingsite.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework-message-queue/BatchConsumer.php on line 154
```

This is so odd.
Please help if you can
Andy

Comment: Did you checked with php version? did you updated php version recently?

Comment: The php version updated automatically on the server from 7.3 to 7.4 I reverted this back to 7.3 but the issue persists. Hosting with SiteGround and using there dashboard to change php versions.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
My hosting company has set php 7.4 as the default so to access v 7.3 when running scripts I had to specify the php version - /usr/local/php73/bin/php-cli

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

- Basically you need check

==========================

```
   Inside your Magento Directory 

           1) Which version of Php you are Using 
                    - sudo update-alternatives --config php

           2) Check your Magento Version 
                   - sudo bin/magento --version

  Make Sure as per your Magento Version - Required Php Version is Selected
```